# Iterating through grep results line by line not delimited by space

Tags: bash, grep

I'm using a bash script to identify where something is used and then find a corresponding reference (name).

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "running, searching for instances of ${1:0:1}/$1"

for i in ls -d Module*; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        if [ -f $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx ]; then
            if grep -qe "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx; then
                echo $i $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx
                grep -B 4 "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx | grep "name"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

I'm trying to change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "running, searching for instances of ${1:0:1}/$1"
for i in ls -d Module*; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        if [ -f $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx ]; then
            if grep -qe "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx; then
                echo $i $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx
                for j in `grep -B 4 "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx | grep "name"` ; do
                    echo $j
                done
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

When I make the above change to iterate through the results, the results are all screwed up. I suspect that my use of `for` is incorrect.

I should note that the results before the change are:

```
$ ./findEllipseType.sh AveragePrice
running, searching for instances of A/AveragePrice
Module-3110 Module-3110/003.Design/003.Data.efx
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_P7sUcAg7EdysLcyAWbYneA" name="EstPrice">
Module-3140 Module-3140/003.Design/003.Data.efx
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_Z2v4IaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="StoresSalePrice">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_bpCVJaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="StoresSalePrice">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_j0crsMnVEeOm9cfLF6jryw" name="EstPrice">
Module-3210 Module-3210/003.Design/003.Data.efx
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_dYMlpaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="GrossPriceP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_duQVQqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="GrossPriceP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_dujQI6W-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="CurrNetPrP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_eNZISqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="GrossPriceP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_eNi5QKW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="PrevGpP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_eNsqQqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="CurrNetPrP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_eNsqSqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="PrevNetPrP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_fRV4kqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="CurrNetPrP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_fRV4mqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="GrossPriceP">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_fgsjMqW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="EstPrice">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_fg1tJaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="ActGrossPr">
Module-3560 Module-3560/003.Design/003.Data.efx
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_xM44IKW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="UnitPrice">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_xOYF8KW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="UnitPrice">
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_xdbOkKW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g" name="AmendPrice">
```

But when I've made the change it appears as (truncated):

```
$ ./findEllipseType.sh AveragePrice
running, searching for instances of A/AveragePrice
Module-3110 Module-3110/003.Design/003.Data.efx
<ownedAttribute
xmi:id="_P7sUcAg7EdysLcyAWbYneA"
name="EstPrice">
Module-3140 Module-3140/003.Design/003.Data.efx
<ownedAttribute
xmi:id="_Z2v4IaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g"
name="StoresSalePrice">
<ownedAttribute
xmi:id="_bpCVJaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g"
name="StoresSalePrice">
<ownedAttribute
xmi:id="_j0crsMnVEeOm9cfLF6jryw"
name="EstPrice">
Module-3210 Module-3210/003.Design/003.Data.efx
<ownedAttribute
xmi:id="_dYMlpaW-EduyI4lEFgFo8g"
```

Looking through the results it appears as though the `for in` is using a space delimiter when I want it to use a line delimiter. How do I change this please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- Change `for i in ls -d Module*; do` to `for i in Module*/;do`
- Replace

```sh
for j in `grep -B 4 "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx | grep "name"` ; do
  echo $j
done
```

with

```sh
while IFS= read -r j; do 
  echo "$j"
done < <(grep -B 4 "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" "$i/003.Design/003.Data.efx" | grep "name")
```

See below for a full discussion.

---

`for i in ls -d Module*; do` will simply enumerate tokens `ls`, `-d` and (possibly expanded) `Module*` instead of enumerating the *output* from an `ls` command.

To correct that immediate problem, you'd have to use command substitution (`for i in $(ls -d Module*; do)`), but that is *not advisable*, because using *globbing (pathname expansion) directly* is the robust, proper solution: `for i in Module*/; do`

Similarly, it's not advisable to use a `for` loop to parse command output line by line, because the output is subject to *word splitting*, among other shell expansions.
**Effectively, the `for` loop enumerates whitespace-separated tokens rather than full lines.**

Using a `while` loop with `IFS= read -r`, with input provided via [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), is the right approach - it ensures that lines are read unmodified.

Also, it's generally advisable to *double-quote* variable *references* to avoid unwanted shell expansions.

A revised form of your code is therefore:

```
shopt -s nullglob  # ensure that a glob matching nothing expands to empty string
for i in Module*/; do 
  if [[ -f "$i/003.Design/003.Data.efx" ]]; then
    if grep -qe "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" "$i/003.Design/003.Data.efx"; then
      echo "$i $i/003.Design/003.Data.efx"
      while IFS= read -r j; do 
        echo "$j"
      done < <(grep -B 4 "Module-0000/003.Design/005.Types/${1:0:1}/$1" "$i/003.Design/003.Data.efx" | grep "name")
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: So, if I read this correctly, the `done < <(grep...` is redirecting the output of the grep command into the while loop?

Comment: @Metalskin: Correct: `<(...)` is a feature called [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), which, loosely speaking, provides the output of a command as a temporary input file. The additional `<` then pipes that file to _stdin_, which is where `read` reads from. Using a pipeline instead - i.e.: `grep ... | while IF= read -r j ....` - is also an option, but only if you do not need access to variable `$j` (and others you may create in the `while` loop) in subsequent commands.

Comment: Turns out the version of bash I use doesn't support process substitution :-(, however I muddled my way through it and got it working. Thank you for your detailed response, it was very helpful.

Comment: @Metalskin My pleasure; glad you got it working. Out of curiosity: what bash version are you using?

Comment: I'm using git bash which uses version 3.1.0(1). It's not been updated despite new releases for at least a couple of years and unfortunately the corporate policy at work dictates Windows 7 as an SOE, so no Linux.

Comment: @Metalskin: I see. It's actually not the _bash version_ that's the problem, but the fact that process substitution is not available on _Windows_, due to lack of support from the OS.

Comment: Ahh no worries., looks like there is some incorrect info out there in regards to git bash then :-)